# tracing the shortestpath using DijkstraAlgorithm

Tags: java, dijkstra

I have a problem in implementing DijkstraAlgorithm.My code is as follows

```
class DijkstraAlgorithmSet {

    private int distances[];
    private java.util.Set<Integer> settled;
    private java.util.Set<Integer> unsettled;
    private int number_of_nodes;
    int source = 0;
    int min;
    int node = 0;

    public DijkstraAlgorithmSet(int number_of_nodes) {
        this.number_of_nodes = number_of_nodes;
        distances = new int[number_of_nodes];
        settled = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        unsettled = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    }
    List<Integer> evaluationNodeList = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> destinationNodeList = new ArrayList();

    public void dijkstra_algorithm() {
        int i, j;
        int evaluationNode;
        int distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;


        for (int k = 0; k < number_of_nodes; k++) {
            distances[k] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        unsettled.add(source);
        distances[source] = 0;
        while (!unsettled.isEmpty()) {
            evaluationNode = getNodeWithMinimumDistanceFromUnsettled();
            unsettled.remove(evaluationNode);
            settled.add(evaluationNode);
            evaluateNeighbours(evaluationNode);
        }
        evaluationNodeList.add(number_of_nodes - 1);
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = settled.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Integer next = iterator.next();
        }

    }

    private int getNodeWithMinimumDistanceFromUnsettled() {


        Iterator<Integer> iterator = unsettled.iterator();
        node = iterator.next();
        min = distances[node];
        System.out.println("minimum>>>>" + min);
        for (int i = 1; i <= distances.length; i++) {
            if (unsettled.contains(i)) {
                if (distances[i] <= min) {
                    min = distances[i];
                    node = i;
                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println("min>>>>" + min);
        return node;
    }
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    private void evaluateNeighbours(int evaluationNode) {
        int edgeDistance = -1;
        int newDistance = -1;
        int destinationNode;
        int temp = 0;
        for (destinationNode = 0; destinationNode < number_of_nodes; destinationNode++) {
            if (!settled.contains(destinationNode)) {
                if (adjacencyMatrix[evaluationNode][destinationNode] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    edgeDistance = adjacencyMatrix[evaluationNode][destinationNode];
                    newDistance = distances[evaluationNode] + edgeDistance;
                    if (newDistance < distances[destinationNode]) {
                        distances[destinationNode] = newDistance;
                        System.out.println("temp>>>>>" + evaluationNode);
                        temp = evaluationNode;
                        System.out.println("destinationNode>>>>>" + destinationNode);

                    }
                    unsettled.add(destinationNode);
                }

            }

        }



    }
```

I wwant to trace the path.But i have not found the path. I got only the final distance using the above code.

Comment: what output do you get? using above code? only starting and ending point?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your algorithm to store in each node the predecessor node in the shortest path.
This way after the algorithm has completed you can just follow the predecessors to the origin and reconstruct the path.

In other words have another array `private int predecessors[];` and remember where the best distance came from:

```
if (newDistance < distances[destinationNode]) {
    distances[destinationNode] = newDistance;
    predecessors[destinationNode] = evaluationNode;
    ...
}
```